# regex for finding text containing no more than one space

Tags: regex

Given this text

> def[][]this[]is[]a[]function[][]5

I'd like a regex able to find test 'this is a function' (a '[]' is a space here).

I need to add robotframework language to ctags. So I've to use egrep like syntax, in the form

--regex-=/regexp/replacement/[kind-spec/][flags]

(see man ctags for more details)

Since in robotframework language a function name con contain a space (but two spaces or tabs separates arguments in a function) I need to "aggregate" a function name with at max one space and no more.

Comment: What engine are you using?

Comment: I need to add support for robotframework to exuberant ctags. 
Section --regex-<LANG>  says that  it's an extended regular expression (roughly that used by egrep).

Comment: Are you asking how to find the text that has two spaces before and two spaces after?

Comment: yes, I need this

Answer (score -1):

```
/[][]+/[]/g
```

Where [] represent spaces.

Comment: this finds spaces surrounding 'this is a function' text, not the text itself.